# NameError: name 'pycrfsuite' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

The following code appears when I am running a cell on Google Colab:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-5f325bc0550d  in <module>()
      4 
      5 TAGGER_PATH = "crf_nlu.tagger"  # path to the tagger- it will save/access the model from here
----> 6 ct = CRFTagger(feature_func=get_features)  # initialize tagger with get_features function
      7 
      8 print("training tagger...")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nltk/tag/crf.py in __init__(self, feature_func, verbose, training_opt)
     81 
     82         self._model_file = ''
---> 83         self._tagger = pycrfsuite.Tagger()
     84 
     85         if feature_func is None:

NameError: name 'pycrfsuite' is not defined
```

This is the code from the cell:

```
# Train the CRF BIO-tag tagger

import pycrfsuite

TAGGER_PATH = "crf_nlu.tagger"  # path to the tagger- it will save/access the model from here
ct = CRFTagger(feature_func=get_features)  # initialize tagger with get_features function

print("training tagger...")
ct.train(training_data, TAGGER_PATH)
print("done")
```

What causes this issue?

I have an import for the *CRFTagger* which is:

> from nltk.tag import CRFTagger

Comment: Has anything with this lib pycrfsuite worked for you before on Google Colab? Seems like it can't find pycrfsuite like it was not installed there

Comment: @FilipA, well, you are right! I tried to install python-crfsuite. However, it requires sklearn-pycrfsuite

Answer (score 2):

I just sorted it out. For the google colab, I had to add the following line:

> pip install sklearn-pycrfsuite

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> pip install python-crfsuite

Scikit-crfsuite provides API similar to scikit-learn library.